# Starting in XSLT - Referencing two SQL tables

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

I'm new here and just starting in XSLT.  I've only had a couple days with it due to a work requirement, so I hope this question isn't totally off base.

I'm working in a software that requires XSLT in its templates that construct e-mails that are sent based on a trigger event.  The event triggers the email which is sent, and the XSLT is what builds the content of the email.

Right now, I'm trying to reference two different tables in the XSLT.  The first table works fine.  I can pull the content without issue.  The second table is where I run into the issues, it either is not linking to the table or does not understand what content to pull.  I assume I need a join, but I'm not able to find a good explanation on how to do that in XML.

The select of Ship_Add1 is not populating, but all the other selects are.  I believe I need to join the two which I can based on an OrderID field, but I can't find how to do so...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">Dear <xsl:value-of select="//Sqls/CustomerName/Row/FirstName" />    <xsl:value-of select="//Sqls/CustomerName/Row/LastName" />, <br />
  <br />
    <tr>
      <td class="ShipName">Shipping Address:</td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="//Sqls/DeliveryTentative/Row/Ship_Add1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit:

The `//Sqls/CustomerName/Row/FirstName` and `LastName` work.  I can get those outputted every time, successfully.

The problem is with getting a value for `//Sqls/DeliveryTentative/Row/Ship_Add1`
I did write a select statement in SQL format as a reporting mechanism that only utilizes SQL, and successfully referenced the table, so I know both the table and the column exists.

I think what the issue is, is that I need to somehow join the two tables together so that the table knows what to provide back for `Ship_Add1`.  That's where I am falling short, I feel.

Edit: I did the Identity Transform and got the following I tried to break it out as best as possible:

272340021581
FirstNameLastName
JohnDoe@JohnDoe.com
JohnDoe@JohnDoe.com
333-333-6666

CompanyName

ClientName

webaddress

32004 329 | MOVED_Planning Fact Sheets1 | ItemFalse

28304 353 | MOVED_Planning Fact Sheets | 50 | ItemsFalse

74404 362 | MOVED_Planning Fact Sheets | 50 | ItemsFalse

32004 sdfsdfsdfsdfs

JohnDoe@JohnDoe.com 
sdfsdf18

Zip Code

asdfsdfsdfsdf

Kentucky | United States | Standard | 4/24/2015 12:05:53 PM4/24/2015 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: 3 things:  you mention both mysql and sql-server.  Which one are you using?  they are not the same thing.  Secondly, where is the sql occurring here?   Thirdly, it would be easier to identify your issue if you provide a sample xml file

Comment: It would be sql-server that I'm using.

The SQL is occurring on the software server.  If it's any help, it's XMPIE uStore.  So as far as a sample XML file, all I have is the code I'm inputting to the GUI editor included in the software suite that is application controlled.

Again, I'm pretty new to this stuff, so please bear with me as I am learning on the fly :)

Comment: okay, please edit your post to include an XML sample (i.e. where is it grabbing the data?)  It's hard o tell why one field might be working and another isn't.  If the data is there, there's likely a syntax error, or the data isn't being properly pulled from the server, so there's nothing there.   I'm gathering the query is outputting some data in xml format, which explains why you are using xslt.  At the very least it would helpful to see the output from the server.

Comment: You cannot write or debug XSLT without seeing the source XML. Use (only) the *identity transform template* to make the XSLT pass-through the input XML to the output *as is*.

Comment: I see what both of you are saying... I can't see the source XML I am assuming because I am stuck using the GUI editor provided by the Application.  And nomistic is correct - it is outputting the First name and Last name successfully, but it is not outputting the Ship_Add1.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion re *identity transform template*?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, honestly... I'm looking into that now.  Seems easy enough, I'll give that a shot and reply back in an edit.

Comment: Updated with what the Identity Transform Template results.

Comment: That's not XML. The identity transform should return XML. If it doesn't, then something else is intervening in the process (or you didn't apply it correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it after all day...

There is an executable SQL behind the software that is used to produce the XML.  For those who are wondering and fighting XMPIE...

This is the Message Template SQL, which then needs to be linked the the message template by Number:

Name: PackingSlip
`exec ('SELECT Ship_Add1 as Mailstop FROM DeliveryTentative WHERE DeliveryTentative.OrderID = ' +@OrderID)`

Then it was simple to get the XSL language written...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tr>
    <td>Mailstop:<xsl:value-of select="//Sqls/Mailstop/Row/Mailstop" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

This displayed back the mailstop or "Ship_Add1 perfectly.

Thanks so much for your help, everyone - It really pointed me in the right direction!  This place rocks!